# What are "C.xxx.xxxxx" symbols in section rodata of the symtab?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, powerpc

Using objdump (option -t), I printed the symbol table of a shared library generated with gcc, for the PowerPC architecture. It contains a bunch of "C.xxx.xxxxx" symbols in the section .rodata, e.g. :

```
0075c0a8 l     O .rodata        0000000e              C.518.39273
```

Of course, there's no such symbol in our C/C++ source files.
What are these symbols related to ?

Comment: A compiler typically produces auxiliary symbols for technological things such as labels, stack unwinding data, helper functions it expects RTL to provide for the program to function etc.

Comment: In this case the symbol is local which is indicated by an `l` in the 2nd column. Therefore it is eliminated by the linker.